# Why am I not able to run .exe files natively on Linux-based systems?

Tags: linux, windows, linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-mint

I am fully aware of products like Wine and PlayOnLinux for using Windows application on Linux, but why am I unable to run .exe files on Linux?  Is it because of something in the architecture of Windows operating systems that Linux doesn't use?  Is it possible to create a linux distro or work with an existing one (Ubuntu, Mint, Debian, etc) to run .exe and .deb?  If it is possible, what could be looked into and researched to be able to do so?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

Comment: *"I am fully aware of products..."* -- Then try to expand that mere  "awareness" into understanding what they actually do.

Comment: You are unable for a lots of reasons. For the most because of different kernels, an `exe` file in Linux is simply a file with execution permissions, so yeah they both serve the same functionality but they are built on a different OS. Even stuff built on BSD would not work on Linux and on Windows, different binary representations.  What you need to overcome this ? an emulator, or even better a virtual machine. What they do ? They make the actual OS kernel work on a different system. Also hardware extensions like VT-x makes this process very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

An executable file is a set of instructions the tells the program loader how to place the program in memory. An executable file can in turn reference shared libraries that are essentially executable files as well so the loading process is recursive.

First of all, the operating systems program loader needs to be able understand executable file format. This, the Linux loader does not do.

Second, any shared libraries referenced by the executable need to be available. Those libraries referenced in a windoze application are not going to be available on a linux system.

Even if you could get the past the first two hurdles, the operating systems would need to respond to system service calls in the same way. When you call an open file system service in Windows a linux system might interpret that as a close file system service call (or anything) (On Intel there are multiple ways of invoking system services).